# Why so many open cursors are used for SELECT query on single table?

Tags: oracle11g, cursor

I have observed `SELECT` statements with high numbers of open cursors in Oracle 11g. For example,

1. ```
   SELECT statement USING 112 OPEN cursors:
   SELECT NVL(MAX(TO_NUMBER(pmd_mdoc_no)),0)+1 FROM t_pm_mdoc;
   ```

   > table T_PM_MDOC has 5 million records.
2. ```
   SELECT PWC_WERKS,PWC_ARBPL 
   FROM T_PM_WK_CTR WHERE PWC_WERKS='077' 
   AND PWC_ARBPL='PPMECDGS';
   ```

   > table t_pm_wk_ctr has 1553 records.

Why are so many implicit cursors used for a `SELECT` query on a single table?

Comment: How many cursors does the second query use?

Comment: What query are you running to give you the number 112?  Your title talks about "implicit cursors", your body talks about "open cursors".  Those are very different things.  And without knowing your query, it's hard to know whether you're measuring actually open cursors or cached cursors or something else.

Comment: Most probably you are worried about why you session has so many open cursors while you are running just one SELECT, the answer is that Oracle do a lot of "implicit selects" in order to parse your statement (check if table exists, checks if column exists, check if you have grants to access that table/column, some other "selects" to build execution plan and so on) Besides this Oracle also do a lot of "selects" to check your credentials during session creation. Some of that cursors remain "open" until the end of session.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, second query uses 16 open cursor

Comment: @Justin Cave, Query is:  "SELECT sid ,sql_id,USER_NAME, COUNT(*) AS "OPEN CURSORS"
FROM v$open_cursor
WHERE USER_NAME = 'PMSUSR' GROUP BY sid ,sql_id,USER_NAME ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;"

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu Velescu, If i ensure that same SQL do not get parsed again and again then I may end up using less cursors ?

Comment: We are working to resolve ORA 01000: Open cursor limits exceeded. For the first query, number of open cursor varies from 20 to 240. I appreciate any help to understand the behavior.

Comment: I guess you are connected with java/php/C# or any other application, most probably you have resultset/statement leak - you need to close the resultset/statement each time you do not need it, otherwise each SELECT will leave an open cursor in the DB.